# Generate bell curve data using Clojure

Tags: clojure

How to generate a normal distribution of values using Clojure? Actually not necessarily a true normal distribution, but one that can be skewed.

As an example I would like to create a function that outputs a generated (pseudo random) number for the concentration of oxygen in air by volume. The lowest possible output should be 19.5% and the greatest possible 23.5%, while the modal value should be 20.95%. The function should work for this 'skewed normal' distribution where the lower portion of the tail has a range of 1.45% and the higher portion a range of 2.55%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to get any distribution you want, if you can plot the function `y=f(x)` that describes the probability density function.

For a Gaussian, this function is f(x)=exp( -(x-m)^2 / (2 * s^2) ) / sqrt(2*pi* s^2)   (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)

Where m is the mean of x and s is the std dev of x.

For a "normal" gaussian where m=0 and s=1, there are "almost never" values outside of +/-3 (exact amount left as an exercise to the reader). Given this approximation, the simplest way to get a gaussian dist is to generate an x floating point value in the interval [-3..3] AND a y value in the interval [0..1].  Then calculate f(x) as above: exp(...) etc.  Then, IFF y<=f(x), use the value x as your random value.  Otherwise, discard both x and y and start over.

While this technique throws away some (or many) values, it is very simple and bulletproof.

You can use a similar method for your "skewed gaussian" approximation, just define your own f(x) as you described.  For a really simple approx, you could even use a straight line approximation from (19.5,0) to (20.95,1) to (23.5,0), where this makes a triangular shape for f(x).  In this case, draw x in the interval [19.5..23.5] and calculate the straight-line formula for the left & right halves for f(x). Draw y in [0..1] as before.

I just found that Wikipedia describes this in more detail:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling

---

**Update:**

If you just want Gaussian random variables (or other common distributions), you can use the [Apache Commons Math library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use Incanter's `sample-normal` to generate (non-skewed) normally distributed numbers.  For example, this will generate 20 normally distributed values with mean 2 and standard deviation 5:

```
(ns foo 
  (:use [incanter.stats]))

(sample-normal 20 :mean 2 :sd 5)
```

You could also use Java's [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) or a better random number generator in Java, such as Sean Luke's [`MersenneTwisterFast`](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esean/research).  To use `MersenneTwisterFast`, for example, download the java source file and put it e.g. in src/java in your Leiningen project tree.  Then add
a line like `:java-source-paths ["src/java"]` to project.clj.  In a Clojure source file:

```
(ns foo
  (:import [ec.util MersenneTwisterFast]))

(defn make-rng
  "Make an instance of a MersenneTwisterFast RNG and flush out its initial
  minimal lack of entropy."
  [seed]
  (let [rng (MersenneTwisterFast. seed)]
    (dotimes [_ 1500] (.nextInt rng)) ; needed because of a quirk of Mersenne Twisters
    rng))

(def my-rng (make-rng 42))

;; Now call this as many times as you want to generate standard Normal data:
(.nextGaussian my-rng)
```

Using Java's `Random` is similar, without the downloading and moving to src/java, etc., but I don't think you'll need to flush Java's `Random` with the 1500 `.nextInt`s (though your random numbers might not be as random as those from a Mersenne Twister).

As [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/173412/19960) at stats.SE explains, you can get an arbitrary normal distribution from a standard normal distribution by multiplying the value above by your desired standard deviation, and then adding the desired mean.

Alan Thompson's answer explains how to produce a truncated distribution from a regular normal distribution.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159640/19960) at stats.SE gives advice relevant to producing a skewed normal distribution from a normal distribution.

EDIT (2021): There are some additional libraries worth exploring that are listed by the SciCloj community project [here](https://scicloj.github.io/pages/libraries/).  I haven't worked with most of these libraries, so I can't give more detailed advice, but it seemed worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is inspired by two of the ideas in Alan Thompson's answer: 'rejection sampling' and using a triangle, rather than a bell curve kind of shape i.e. scaling.

```
(defn generator [modal-val low-val high-val]
  (fn []
    (let [gen-val (fn []
                    (let [diff-range (- high-val low-val)
                          picked-in-range (rand diff-range)
                          perhaps-res (+ low-val picked-in-range)
                          ;; partial distance left or right, that will be negative if to left
                          modal-delta (- perhaps-res modal-val)
                          extremity (if (neg? modal-delta) low-val high-val)
                          ;; full distance left or right, that will be negative if to left
                          total-dist (- extremity modal-val)
                          closeness-to-modal (- 1 (/ modal-delta total-dist))
                          ]
                      (when (<= (rand) closeness-to-modal)
                        perhaps-res)))]
      (first (drop-while nil? (repeatedly gen-val))))))
```

It can be used like this:

```
((generator 20.95 19.5 23.5))
```

Comment: fwiw, Clojure's `rand` is based on Java's `Random`, so if the latter isn't a sufficiently high-quality random number generator for a given use, then `rand` won't be either.  For many situations it's good enough, though.